I can not match both two-letter and five-letter language codes from the `LANG` environment variable in an `if` statement in Nushell
Explanation
It was easy to implement a translation system in Bash and Zsh.
Now, it is particularly challenging to implement a translation system in Nushell because Nushell is different from Bash and Zsh.
I am trying to match both two-letter language codes (like en for English, pt for Portuguese and European Portuguese) and five-letter language codes (like pt_BR for Brazilian Portuguese) correctly, and to fall back the non-existent languages to the English version.
However, my current code only matches the two characters of the LANG environment value for all other languages.
Here is my small code:
let language = $env.LANG | str substring 0..1

let translations = {
  "pt":
  {
    "hello_world": "Olá, gajo",
  },
  "pt_BR":
  {
    "hello_world": "Oi, garoto",
  },
  _: 
  {
    "hello_world": "Hello, guy",
  }
}

let current_translations = $translations | get $lang_code
let hello_world = $current_translations.hello_world

I ran the following commands in the terminal, using Nushell:
$env.LANG = "pt_BR.UTF-8"; source 01-translations; print $hello_world
$env.LANG = "pt_PT.UTF-8"; source 01-translations; print $hello_world
$env.LANG = "es_ES.UTF-8"; source 01-translations; print $hello_world

I also tried to implement another alternative:
let language = $env.LANG

let lang_code = if $language == "pt_BR.UTF-8" {
  $language | str substring 0..5
} else {
  $language | str substring 0..1
}

Actual behaviour

The code correctly returns all two-letter language codes, including pt and displays the correct translation.
For other two-letter languages codes that do not exist in the translation system, the code failed to fall back to the default English version.
For other five-letter languages codes, if you select pt_BR.UTF-8, it only returns the European Portuguese version incorrectly, causing the lookup in the translations table to fail.

Desired behaviour
I want to handle both two-letter and five-letters language codes like pt and five-letter codes like pt_BR, and to fall back the non-existent two-letter and five-letters language codes to the default English version.
Update
I tested the other alternative, and it worked, but the code is ugly:
let lang = if ($env.LANG =~ 'fr') { "fr" } else if ($env.LANG =~ 'pt_BR') { "pt_BR" } else if ($env.LANG =~ 'pt') { "pt" } else if ($env.LANG =~ 'it') { "it" } else { "default" }

let hello = $translations | get $lang | get hello
let bye = $translations | get $lang | get bye
let how_are_you = $translations | get $lang | get how_are_you
let where_are_you_from = $translations | get $lang | get where_are_you_from


You should check for the longer strings first, e.g. pt_BR before pt, else pt will match both.

I added an update. As you suggested me, I tested another different alternative, but the code is ugly.

If nushell has a case statement, it would be useful here.

I don't know nushell but it seems you could use a table with 2 columns,
the pattern and the resulting language, and then iterate through the rows through the filter command, using a closure or function that tests the  environment language against the pattern, and if ok, returns the language.
let data = [[pattern lang];
            [fr      fr],
            [pt_BR   pt_BR],
            [pt      pt],
            [it      it],
            [.       default]]
$data | filter {|e| $env.LANG =~ $e.pattern} | first | get lang

You don't seem to need to quote simple alphanumeric strings.
I tried the following too but it gave an empty list for some reason.
$data | filter {|e| if $want =~ $e.pattern {$e.lang} }

